# VMnetwork adapter not detected in hyperv vitual machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hypervisor

i have hyperV server running on which , i have just created a windows server 2008 virtual machine, where in that virtual machine network adapter is not detected. how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

@kaustubh93 Try installing a LEGACY network adapter.  For machines as old as Win2K8 Server, the default network adapters may not work (did not for me), but installing a Legacy adapter did the trick.

This fix (using a Legacy adapter) worked this evening on a Windows 10 Pro installation running Hyper-V Client.  I'd installed a Windows 7 Pro VM, but it wouldn't access the Internet via the Virtual Switch (external).  Once I installed the legacy NIC, I had Internet access from within the VM.

Windows 2008 R2 is essentially Windows 7 anyway, so this solution is likely to work for you as well.

Jeff W.
Reading, PA

Answer (score 0):

To add a network adapter

Open Hyper-V Manager. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Hyper-V Manager.

In the results pane, under Virtual Machines, select the virtual machine that you want to configure.

In the Action pane, under the virtual machine name, click Settings.

In the navigation pane, click Add Hardware.

On the Add Hardware page, choose a network adapter or a legacy network adapter.

Click Add. The Network Adapter or Legacy Network Adapter page appears.

Under Network, select the virtual network you want to connect to.

If you want to configure a static MAC address or virtual LAN identifier, specify the numbers you want to use.

Click OK.

More : [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770380.aspx) [troubleshooting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742454.aspx)